# Watch a folder structure for changes and process files accordingly

Tags: java, file, jakarta-ee

I am facing the following situation ... somewhere in my filesystem () i am accepting files from a third party application. For example in folder c:\temp

These files contain specific metadata and i will have to do the following actions:

a) rellocate according to metadata (so first i will parse them) in a 2-level structure such as:
C:\temp\idXXX\idYYYY\fileZZZ
each idYYYY folder can contain multiple files
each idXXX folder can contain multiple folders (e.g. idYYYY, idYYYYE etc.)
in the root folder there could be multiple idXXXX type of folders

b) after reallocating these files i should monitor each 1st level directory (idXXXX) for changes for a time interval

c) if no changes found (no additional folders/files created) then i should zip it and send it somewhere!

d) implement such a service to run continiously in the background ... just polling this root dir

I am trying to find a library in java that could manage this whole business scenario!

any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`WatchService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) to monitor your directories:

```
WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
WatchKey watchKey = path.register(watchService,
                                  ENTRY_CREATE,
                                  ENTRY_DELETE,
                                  ENTRY_MODIFY);
```

The rest is just implementing your logic using the usual `File` methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to watch for changes, you may save the files' names in a String array and read them in another, so comparing them with a `for` loop will tell you any new file in that folder.

```
for (i= 0; i< oldfiles.length(); i++){
if (oldfiles[i] != newfiles[i]){  //in case there's a difference
//your code here
}
}
```

note that if no filename were erased from `newfiles[]` and some were added, `newfiles[]` will be bigger than `oldfiles[]` and precisely those names will be the new ones, so you should continue reading the newfiles[] array:

```
for (i=oldfiles.length() + 1; i<newfiles.length(); i++){
// your code here
}
```

finally you should copy the `newfiles[]`array into the `oldfiles[]`array for the next comparison

Hope it helps. I'm not sure if java-ee syntax is the same as standard java's.